# 3D geometry with spheres and cylinders

Tags: geometry

The problem goes as follows: Two metal balls are placed in a cylinder containing water. The lower has a radius of 7cm and the upper has a radius of 3cm. The diameter of the cylinder is 18cm. The total volume of water in the cylinder is 2414/3 x Pi cm3. The volume of water that has to be poured out so that there is just enough water to cover both balls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the volume of the water when the spheres are in the container.
[image]